# The efficiency compare between Flatten[#, 1] & and Join @@ # &

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Err.. Often I met the situation to join lists at the first level and I used to just `Flatten[#, 1] & @` them. However, I found (*when glance over the mathematica.stackexchange.com*) someone else prefers `Join @@ # &`. They are equal in output when the inputs are `{list1, list2, ...listn}`, so I wonder if there are any differences in efficiency. Define:

```
f := Flatten[#, 1] &; g = Join @@ # &;
```

and the test lists:

```
lists = Table[ConstantArray[{1, 2}, 2^n], {n, 1, 22}];
```

test:

```
ftime = AbsoluteTiming[f@#;] & /@ lists;
gtime = AbsoluteTiming[g@#;] & /@ lists;
```

with output:

```
{{0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., 
Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., 
Null}, {0.001000, Null}, {0.007000, Null}, {0.004000, 
Null}, {0.007000, Null}, {0.015001, Null}, {0.030002, 
Null}, {0.062004, Null}, {0.138008, Null}, {0.266015, 
Null}, {0.529030, Null}, {1.053060, Null}}(*ftime*)

{{0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., 
Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0., Null}, {0.001000, 
Null}, {0., Null}, {0.004000, Null}, {0.003000, Null}, {0.006000, 
Null}, {0.013001, Null}, {0.026002, Null}, {0.052003, 
Null}, {0.102006, Null}, {0.204012, Null}, {0.428024, 
Null}, {0.845048, Null}}(*gtime*)
```

plot:

```
ListLinePlot[{Log10 /@ ftime[[All, 1]], Log10 /@ gtime[[All, 1]]}, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {Table[{2 n, 2^(2 n)}, {n, 0, 27}], 
Table[{n, NumberForm[10^n, 3]}, {n, -10, 27, 0.4}]}, ImageSize -> 600, 
PlotLegends -> {f, g}]
```

[image]

seems `Join @@ # &` approach is slightly faster...

Then my questions are:

1. is `Join @@ # &` approach always faster?
2. why there is a peak in length-time plot at around length ~ $ 2^{13} $?

Comment: You might like also to consider the case of packed arrays (use `Range[2]` in place of `{1,2}` in your `lists`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a V10 comparison.

```
f = Flatten[#, 1] &;
g = Join @@ # &;
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
```

With packed arrays, also suggested by Simon Woods:

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g}, ConstantArray[Range[2], #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 1*^7, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With the OP's original arrays.

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g}, ConstantArray[{1, 2}, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 1*^7, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The main advantage of `Flatten` with packed arrays is that `Apply` unpacks the first level, which accounts for much of the difference in time.  On unpacked arrays `Apply` performs better on arrays of length of about 100 or greater.  The little jump in the timing of `Flatten` is consistently around 8000 - 10000 as observed by the OP.  If the base array is lengthened by a factor of ten, we see that the jump is around 800, so perhaps it is memory related. (If so, then the jump might vary by system. I'm on a MacBook Pro, i7 2.7GHz.)  It will probably take knowledge of the internal workings of `Flatten` to answer the question.

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g}, 
 ConstantArray[
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, #] &,
 PowerRange[10, 2*^6, 2], 
 "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please add `Catenate` to this answer, or I shall post a separate one.

Comment: Looks like I forgot about this (comment above), but still I think it should be done.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Me, too. I think `BenchmarkPlot` was broken at the time, or at least I recall having trouble with it.  Works now in V12, with different labels than above. I've run it with `Catenate`. Not sure when I'll have time to post. http://i.stack.imgur.com/sZhvp.png