# How to plot equally discrete points?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to create a table of equally discrete points and plot them with:

```
a = 5
ListPlot[Table[{a/9*(i - 1), a/9*(j - 1)}, {i, n}, {j, n}]]
```

But I cannot plot it with ListPlot because it creates a table with depth of 3. How to deal with that?

Comment: You may wish to see [(75590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75590/121)

Comment: Sure, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = 5;
n = 30;
ListPlot[Flatten[
  Table[{a/9*(i - 1), a/9*(j - 1)}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}], 1]]
```