# Is it possible to avoid unpacking when merging Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, packed-arrays

For example, if we have

```
assoc = 
  AssociationThread[{1, 2, 3} -> RandomReal[1., {3, 10}]];
```

and

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ/@ assoc
```

gives

```
<|1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True|>
```

so each Value is packed array.

Now, I want to Merge several Assocation like this. Then I checked packedness,

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ Merge[{assoc, assoc}, Flatten]
```

it gives

```
<|1 -> False, 2 -> False, 3 -> False|>
```

It unpacks, even though `Flatten` should not unpack list.

So is it possible to avoid this unpacking in `Merge`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One can use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) to see how [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) is being used by [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge):

```
TracePrint[
    Merge[{assoc,assoc}, Flatten],
    _Flatten,
    TraceAction->Print@*Developer`PackedArrayForm
];
```

> Flatten[{PackedArray[Real,<10>],PackedArray[Real,<10>]}]
>
> Flatten[{PackedArray[Real,<10>],PackedArray[Real,<10>]}]
>
> Flatten[{PackedArray[Real,<10>],PackedArray[Real,<10>]}]

Notice how [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge) builds a list of two packed arrays, and then flattens them. This is why the the arrays become unpacked. To workaround this, you can either convert the list of two packed arrays into a packed array first:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ Merge[{assoc, assoc}, Flatten @* Developer`ToPackedArray]
```

> <|1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True|>

Or you can use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join) with [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply) (as in Henrik's answer, but using slot free syntax):

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ Merge[{assoc, assoc}, Apply[Join]]
```

> <|1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True|>

Comment: Hi, Carl Woll, I posted a summary answer, and there are some issue I don't understand. Would you to have a look?

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using `Merge`, you can also use `AssociationTranspose` which is often much faster than `Merge` and doesn't unpack:

```
m1 = Merge[{assoc, assoc}, Flatten];
m2 = Flatten /@ GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose[{assoc, assoc}];
m1 === m2
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ m1
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ m2
```

> True
>
> <|1 -> False, 2 -> False, 3 -> False|>
>
> <|1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True|>

Frankly, `AssociationTranspose` + `Map` is pretty much just superior to `Merge` like 99% of the time.

Answer (score 11):

`Join` tries to pack whenever it is possible:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ Merge[{assoc, assoc}, Join @@ # &]
```

> <|1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True|>

One might expect that `Catenate` should also work, but it does not.

Answer (score 5):

Here goes a self answer.

To be honest, I almost decide to delete my post right after I posted. Because I naively thought unpacking may be unavoidable. Luckily, I keep this post, and this problem becomes more interesting. **Thank you so much to @Carl Woll, @Sjoerd Smit and @Henrik Schumacher for providing great answers. Learned a lot.**

Now, I summarize and add some benchmarks to other answers.

First, two related post on flatten or join pure list(not association)

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75592/4742
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184578/4742

these two post suggest us, we need to differentiate three cases:

1. completely packed array
2. completely unpacked array
3. sublist packed array(unpacked at first level)

Briefly,

1. for completely packed array, `Flatten` is **much** faster to `Apply[Join]`, because `Apply` unpacked first level.
2. for completely unpacked array, 'Apply[Join]` is faster, but timing is much closer than completely packed.
3. for sublist packed array, `Apply[Join]` is **much** faster to `Flatten`

Before benchmark, we need routines to generated three kind of array

```
ClearAll[genCompletelyPacked];
genCompletelyPacked[sublistLen_, totalLen_] := ConstantArray[Range[sublistLen], totalLen];
ClearAll[genCompletelyUnpacked];
genCompletelyUnpacked[sublistLen_, totalLen_] := 
  Developer`FromPackedArray@genCompletelyPacked[sublistLen, totalLen];
ClearAll[genSublistPacked];
genSublistPacked[sublistLen_, totalLen_] := 
  Developer`ToPackedArray /@ genCompletelyUnpacked[sublistLen, totalLen];
```

and define below function (I add `Catenate` suggested by  Mr.Wizard in other post)

```
f = Flatten[#, 1] &;
g = Join @@ # &;
h = Catenate[#] &;
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
```

Below for every case, I give two benchmark: one for small sublist, the other for long sublist.

## complete packed array

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g, h}, genCompletelyPacked[10, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^3, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g, h}, genCompletelyPacked[1000, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^3, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

The jumping maybe due to memory issue as suggested by Michael E2.

## completely unpacked array

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g, h}, genCompletelyUnpacked[10, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^3, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g, h}, genCompletelyUnpacked[1000, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^3, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

## sublist packed array

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g, h}, genSublistPacked[10, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^3, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f, g, h}, genSublistPacked[1000, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^3, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

## Now, we return to `Association` case:

As point out by Carl Woll, `Merge` simply put list together, and resulting sublist packed case that is unpacked at the first level(In this sense, unpacking is unavoidable in `Merge`, because first level is unpacked). So we can envisage, `Apply[Join]` will be much faster, however, we will see things getting a little different.

Sjoerd Smit suggested quite novel `GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose`which is even better, because it doesn't unpack at all, and we can give much hope`GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose` will be much faster. However, we will see this is not always the case.

First, we define routines to generate list of Association with values are packed list.

```
ClearAll[genAssoc];
genAssoc[len_, n_] := 
  Table[AssociationThread[{1, 2, 3} -> RandomReal[1., {3, len}]], n];
```

and several functions

```
f1 = Merge[#, Flatten] &;
f2 = Merge[#, Apply[Join]] &;
f3 = Merge[#, Catenate] &;
f4 = Flatten /@ GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose[#] &;

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, genAssoc[10, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^4, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, genAssoc[1000, #] &, 
 PowerRange[10, 10^4, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

you can clearly see some peculiarity as I pointed out previous. For example,

1. `AssociationTranspose` is only good for small sublist.
2. For small sublist, `Flatten` becomes comparable to `Apply[Join]` when number of association becomes large.

I have no answer, waiting other to explain.